# How do i do Flex Grid in bootstrap

Tags: css, grid, flexbox

So I have a little problem with grid system. I want to make grid like McDonalds site did.

So if I zoom out on this site, the grid is not changing! I mean the height and widht is the same, just the content is changing. I don't know how to do it. Please for help

McDonald site http://mcdonalds.pl/

My example:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some example code on what you have already tried. It will be easier to analyse your issue.

Comment: I wanted jist some example... I jused simple 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
but those columns are stretching like more width less height
I think i wrote it pretty clearly, i want to do smf like on this site, i said what and i gave you the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another try. You can use vieport hight and width in your CSS (i.e. `height: 50vh`):

It is not a perfect example:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cover-img {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/82/64/7e/82647eca04687361c6d515f335d4c08a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.some-box {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 50vh;
  line-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 6vh;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 38vw !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="cover-img">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="some-box">
        Stay the same size
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="some-box">
        Stay the same size
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: Viewport works like percentages

A little closer on what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for, but I gave it a shot

Run the snipped below, activate "Full Page" and zoom in and out:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cover-img {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/82/64/7e/82647eca04687361c6d515f335d4c08a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="cover-img">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p>Some content here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Not really, cuz nav bar is changing height i mean it is getting smaller if i zoom out. I want it to stay the same size even if i zoom out.
look at this http://e-skinbet.pl/ . I want those 2 divs under slider to stay the same size even if i zoom out. Now they are changing height

Comment: Background is working good in you example, it stay the same even if i zoom out

Comment: added another answer. not perfect though.

Comment: Hey, i don t want to create new topic, cuz its probably small problem, but can you look at this, and can you tell me why there is margin on the right site? http://e-skinbet.pl/

Comment: It has something to do with your markup in your footer... remove the footer and have a look.